# Percentage relations between x and y.(Relation between two variables)

Tags: percentages

I would like to know easiest method to solve following:

**Que 1:**

If **10% of x=y**, then **y% of 30** is same as **what % of x**?

**My Approach:**

Step 1: (10 * x)/100 = (10 * y)/100

Step 2: (30 * y)/100 = (3 * y)/10

Don't know further.

**Que 2:**

What **percentage of numberes** from 1 to 89 are divisible by 5?

**My Approach:**

Step 1: Total numberes divisible by 5 from 1-89 = 17

Step 2: Considering 90 as 100%

Step 3: So 17 is what % of that

Which i solve like

(17 * 100)/90 = 18.888%

I get **ans: 18.8888%**, but i think i am wrong, help here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question $1$, you have: $\dfrac{x}{10} = y \Rightarrow \dfrac{y}{100}\cdot 30 = \dfrac{k}{100}\cdot x=\dfrac{k}{100}\cdot 10y\Rightarrow k = ?$

For question $2$, you have $17$ numbers that are multiple of $5$ out of $89$ numbers. Thus the percentage is $\dfrac{17}{89}\cdot 100\text{%} \approx 19 \text{%}$

Comment: I got the answer for second one i don't know why i took 90 instead of 89.  Thank You very much.

Comment: I still don't get the first one.

Comment: For the first one, $k$ is the answer. Can you solve for $k$?

Comment: I know answer for first one is `3%`, but i still don't know how?

Comment: The equation implies $10k = 30 \Rightarrow k = ?$

Comment: `10% of x=y` was confusing me. But it's clear now. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

For the 1st one: $10\%$ of $x=y$, then $y\%$ of $30$ is same as what $\%$ of $x$?

Consider "of" as multiplication, so 
$10/100=1/10=y\%$

Now $y\%$ of $30$ means,
$1/10*30=3$.
So the answer is $3$.